# Is there any VBA code to sort data at specific intervals in a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

[My data in the way it is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KLt.jpg)

In my data I want to sort data for Bank 1 as per "Nature of Income" column ascending order, for Bank 2 as per "Nature of Income" column ascending order and so on for all banks. But the bank name is written only once in starting row for the bank. There can be many banks and much data in each bank, so if I get a VBA code to sort data with 1 click it will be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: where you get banks data from?

Answer (score 0):

Code comments explain process.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortAreas()

    Dim a As Long

    'define the worksheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        'used range in column D
        With .Range(.Cells(4, "D"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))

            'all dates in column D
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

                'loop through Areas of discontiguous range
                For a = 1 To .Areas.Count

                    'identify Area and expand to 4 columns wide
                    With .Areas(a).Resize(, 4)

                        'sort on the third column in ascending order
                        .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 3), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

                    End With

                Next a

            End With

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```